# Convert time into ISO from a list of records : BS4 Python

Tags: python, datetime, beautifulsoup

I am scraping information for a website and i am able to retrieve all the information. After retrieving all information, i store them to a list.

The list contains timestamp in this format 25-10-2018 09:00, i want to convert it to ISO. I know dateutil can be used for this but i am not able find a right approach for all values. can somebody help ?

Source code:

```
# -*- coding utf-8 -*-
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
import shutil
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import uuid
import csv
import dateutil.parser as parser
import pandas as pd

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


class crawlOcean():

    def __init__(self):
        print("hurray33")
        global downloadDir
        global uFileName
        global filname
        downloadDir = ""
        uFileName = str(uuid.uuid4())
        filname = downloadDir + uFileName + ".csv"
        pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
        pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", downloadDir)
        fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                          "attachment/csv")
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
        #self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        print("hurray")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        self.driver.get("http://www.epa.ie/hydronet/#Water%20Levels")
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

  def crawl(self):
        print("see")
        driver = self.driver
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800)")
        driver.find_element_by_id("dijit_MenuItem_3_text").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="All"]').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="Active EPA/LA (239)"]').click()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        headers = []
        for m in soup.find_all("th"):
            headers.append(m.get_text())
        print(headers)
        content = []
        finalContent = []
        filtter = ['km²']
        new_data = [[c.text.rstrip(" km²") for c in i.find_all('td')]  for i in soup.find_all('table')[5::]]
        print(new_data)
        """filtter = ['km²']
        for table in soup.find_all("table")[5::]:
            for row in table.find_all("tr"):
                contentCells = []
                for cells in row.find_all("td"):
                    contentCells.append(cells.get_text())
            content.append(contentCells)
        for idx, v in enumerate(content):
            for t in filtter:
                content[idx] = [i.replace(t, '') for i in content[idx]]
                #.append(timerecorded)
        print(content)"""
        print(content)
        with open(filname, 'w', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(headers)
            writer.writerows(new_data)
        driver.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = crawlOcean()
    obj.crawl()
```

Output:

```
['Station number', 'Station name', 'Waterbody', 'Status', 'Type of Gauge', 'Catchment area', 'Data Provider', 'River Basin', 'Timestamp', 'Value', 'Unit']
[['14107', 'BAYLOUGH BR.', 'BARROW', 'Active', 'Recorder', '431.50 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Barrow', '25-10-2018 09:00', '58.419', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['18118', 'SHANBALLYMORE', 'SPRING', 'Active', 'Recorder', '0.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Blackwater (Munster)', '25-10-2018 09:00', '0.432', '---'], ['14108', 'BALLYNAFAGH', 'STREAM', 'Active', 'Recorder', '0.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Barrow', '25-10-2018 09:00', '84.531', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['14104', 'GREESEMOUNT', 'GREESE', 'Active', 'Recorder', '74.60 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Barrow', '25-10-2018 08:00', '90.877', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['14100', 'KYLE SPRING', 'SPRING', 'Active', 'Recorder', '0.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Barrow', '17-10-2018 14:15', '91.595', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['03059', 'DRUMULLY BR.', 'MOUNTAIN WATER', 'Active', 'Staff Gauge Only', '0.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Blackwater (Ulster)', '01-10-2018 12:45', '100.280', 'm (TBM)'], ['03070', 'EMY LOUGH', 'EMY LOUGH', 'Active', 'Recorder', '', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Blackwater (Ulster)', '25-10-2018 09:00', '50.884', 'm OD (Poolbeg)'], ['03057', 'EMYVALE WEIR', 'MOUNTAIN WATER', 'Active', 'Recorder', '37.80 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Blackwater (Ulster)', '25-10-2018 09:00', '52.431', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['18048', 'DROMCUMMER', 'BLACKWATER [MUNSTER]', 'Active', 'Recorder', '867.70 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Blackwater (Munster)', '25-10-2018 01:00', '60.605', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['14057', 'TIMOLIN', 'BOTHOGUE', 'Active', 'Recorder', '18.20 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Barrow', '25-10-2018 09:00', '89.953', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['28011', 'DOO LOUGH OUTFLOW', '---', 'Active', 'Recorder', '22.81 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Annageeragh-Annagh-Creegh', '25-10-2018 09:00', '80.743', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['07071', 'SKEAGH', 'SKEAGH L.', 'Active', 'Recorder', '5.30 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Boyne', '15-08-2018 14:00', '149.503', 'm OD (Poolbeg)'], ['03051', 'FAULKLAND', 'BLACKWATER (MONAGHAN)', 'Active', 'Recorder', '143.20 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Blackwater (Ulster)', '19-09-2018 17:00', '41.572', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['07077', 'WHITE LOUGH.', 'ANNAGH OR WHITE LOUGH', 'Active', 'Recorder', '0.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Boyne', '05-09-2018 13:30', '105.169', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['10038', 'DRUIDS GLEN', 'STREAM', 'Active', 'Recorder', '16.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Potters-Redcross-Three Mile Water', '25-10-2018 09:00', '19.377', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['36031', 'LISDARN', 'CAVAN', 'Active', 'Recorder', '63.80 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Erne', '25-10-2018 09:00', '52.317', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['07074', 'BALLANY', 'LENE L.', 'Active', 'Recorder', '13.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Boyne', '25-10-2018 09:00', '92.667', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['16047', 'CARROWCLOGH', 'ARA', 'Active', 'Recorder', '44.10 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Suir', '25-10-2018 08:00', '80.820', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['30012', 'CLAREGALWAY', 'CLARE', 'Active', 'Recorder', '1072.90 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Corrib', '24-10-2018 20:30', '6.355', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['16045', 'BALLYSHONOCK RESRVR.', 'DAWN', 'Active', 'Recorder', '5.20 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Suir', '09-08-2018 13:15', '89.683', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['07078', 'LOUGH BANE', 'BANE L.', 'Active', 'Recorder', '', 'Environmental Protection Agency', '---', '25-10-2018 09:00', '111.051', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['10028', 'KNOCKNAMOHILL', 'AUGHRIM', 'Active', 'Recorder', '203.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Avoca', '24-10-2018 20:00', '21.322', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['29071', 'CUTRA', 'L.    CUTRA', 'Active', 'Recorder', '123.80 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Kinvarra', '25-10-2018 08:15', '32.694', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['25070', 'WHITEBRIDGE.', 'L.ENNELL', 'Active', 'Recorder', '147.80 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Shannon', '25-10-2018 09:00', '78.934', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['29018', 'CLARINBRIDGE SPRING', 'SPRING', 'Active', 'Recorder', '', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Kilcogan', '27-09-2018 12:30', '2.926', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['25072', 'CAPTAIN S HILL', 'OWEL L.', 'Active', 'Recorder', '22.60 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Shannon', '25-10-2018 09:00', '96.146', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['10021', 'COMMON S ROAD', 'SHANGANAGH', 'Active', 'Recorder', '32.50 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Loughlinstown', '25-10-2018 08:00', '10.806', 'm OD (Poolbeg)'], ['26204', 'BALLYMARTIN', 'HIND', 'Active', 'Recorder', '44.70 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Shannon', '25-10-2018 09:00', '40.009', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['33001', 'GLENAMOY', 'GLENAMOY', 'Active', 'Recorder', '76.10 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Glenamoy-Ballinglen-Glencullen', '25-10-2018 09:00', '3.901', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['22031', 'KILLARNEY SW (New)', 'L. LEANE TRIB', 'Active', 'Recorder', '0.06 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Laune', '21-08-2018 11:15', '19.570', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['32076', 'DOO LOUGH', 'DOO LOUGH [MAYO]', 'Active', 'Recorder', '0.00 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Owenglin-Dawros-Culin-Traheen', '03-09-2018 11:30', '30.237', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['32073', 'LETTERETTRIM', 'L.    FEE', 'Active', 'Recorder', '15.70 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Carrownisky-Owenwee-Carrowbeg', '25-10-2018 09:00', '44.589', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['32070', 'L.FEEAGH', 'L.    FEEAGH', 'Active', 'Recorder', '84.30 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Srahmore', '25-10-2018 09:00', '10.852', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['32026', 'BUNDORRAGHA', 'BUNDORRAGHA', 'Active', 'Recorder', '48.30 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Owenglin-Dawros-Culin-Traheen', '25-10-2018 09:00', '3.358', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['25046', 'LISMOYNY', 'BROSNA', 'Active', 'Recorder', '304.50 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Shannon', '25-10-2018 09:00', '57.021', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['35073', 'L.GILL', 'L.GILL', 'Active', 'Recorder', '362.60 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Garvogue', '25-10-2018 09:00', '3.823', 'm OD Malin (OSGM15)'], ['25044', 'COOLE', 'KILMASTULLA', 'Active', 'Recorder', '92.54 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Shannon', '25-10-2018 08:15', '29.649', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['35072', 'TRASGARVE', 'L.    EASKY', 'Active', 'Recorder', '10.70 km²', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Easky-Dunneil', '06-09-2018 10:45', '183.646', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)']
```

Thanks,

Comment: How do you want `25-10-2018 09:00` to looks like after transformation?

Comment: @Andersson it should be like this 25-10-2018T09:00Z for all records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply below to yout `contentCells` list

```
import re
from datetime import datetime as dt

contentCells = [dt.strptime(i, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M').strftime('%d-%m-%YT%H:%MZ') if re.match("\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}", i) else i for i in contentCells]
```

Comment: i am getting this error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: @NorthernShadow , `contentCells` is a list of text nodes from each `td`, right?

Comment: yes, nested like this `[['14107', 'BAYLOUGH BR.', 'BARROW', 'Active', 'Recorder', '431.50', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Barrow', '25-10-2018 09:00', '58.419', 'm OD Malin (OSGM02)'], ['18118', 'SHANBALLYMORE', 'SPRING', 'Active', 'Recorder', '0.00', 'Environmental Protection Agency', 'Blackwater (Munster)', '25-10-2018 09:00', '0.432', '---']]`

Comment: @NorthernShadow Oh... That the problem - it should not be nested :) Try to replace `...for i in contentCells` with `...for i in contentCells[0]`

Comment: @NorthernShadow try to apply it to each list with `for` loop

Comment: fixed it by this approach `new_data = [[dt.strptime(i, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M').strftime('%d-%m-%YT%H:%MZ') if re.match("\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}",i) else i for i in m] for m in new_data]`

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('25-10-2018 09:00', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M').isoformat()
```

It won't have the `Z` because the original datetime doesn't have timezone information, but you can just append it if you want.